# Why does f' = 0 gives the min or max?

Tags: derivatives

I understand how to calculate it, but I am just curious, why actually it works? Do we have a proof that it always works?

Comment: It's the other way around: if a differentiable function at $\;x_0\;$ has an extreme value there then $\;f'(x_0)=0\;$ . This is Fermat's (go figure!) Theorem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take $f\colon x\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto x^3$. Then $f^\prime(0)=0$, yet $0$ is not an extremum (only an inflection point).

As DonAtonio said, the converse is true — if $x$ is an extremum of a differentiable function $f$, then $f^\prime(0)=0$. A way to see it is that the curve of $f$ goes from "going up" to "going down" (or vice-versa), so the slope (derivative) must be zero (horizontal) at the extremum. Or, to prove it, consider the definition of the derivative as the limit of
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$
when $h\to 0$. If $f(x)$ is a maximum, then for $h < 0$ this is $\geq 0$ (so the limit when $h\nearrow 0$ is), while for $h > 0$ this is $\leq 0$ (so the limit when $h\searrow 0$ is). Hence the limit is $0$.

(similarly if $f(x)$ is a minimum)

Answer (score 1):

Take an interval and draw in there a continuous function. Draw a line that is tangent to an extreme of that function. What is the value of your line's slope? Match it with the definition of *derivative*. What does that suggest to you?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Basically, a maximum or minimum is defined as when the function goes from going up (positive slope) to going down (negative slope) or vice versa. When the slope is 0 it's exactly between going up and going down, or a point where the curve flattens out but doesn't change direction (as in C), so the places that have slope 0 and change direction (aren't inflection points) are maximums and minimums.

Comment: This explanation, besides being way non-formal, is seriously wrong, and the drawing itself gives a hint: at the point $\;C\;$ the function' derivative (assuming $\;f\;$ is differentiable and etc.) is **zero**, and that point is *not* an extreme point but in fact, if we're going by the drawing, an inflection point, thus rendering the last words above wrong.

Comment: Modified my statement. My goal was to be understandable, so I avoided a traditional proof.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where a differentiable function $f(x)$ has a minimum at the point $x_{0}$. By definition, there exists a $\epsilon-$neighborhood
$$
  x = \left\{ x\in\mathbb{R} \colon \left| x - x_{0} \right| < \epsilon \right\}
$$ 
with $\epsilon>0$ where $f(x) > f(x_{0})$.

If we constrain $\delta < \epsilon$, then 
$$
\frac{f(x+\delta) - f(x)} {\delta} > 0.
$$
So within the $\epsilon-$neighborhood, a $\delta-$sequence produces a limit which approaches 0 from above.

A similar argument holds for approaching the minimum from the left.